# Composing applicative functions

Tags: haskell, functor, applicative, function-composition

Please implement the function:

```
composeApplicative :: (Applicative f) => f (b -> c) -> f (a -> b) -> f (a -> c)
```

Such that:

```
(composeApplicative f g) <*> x == f <*> (g <*> x)
```

Or alternatively, explain why this can not be done?

Comment: `composeApplicative p q = (.) <$> p <*> q`

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it likely is homework and the OP has shown no effort.

Comment: Not homework, I tried and got to `(\x -> f <*> g <*> x)` which obviously wasn't what I was looking for. I was trying to make a newtype wrapped applicative function a member of Control.Category. Seeing the answer now it looks obvious but I bashed around for about 20 minutes and got nowhere near it.

Comment: @Clinton Then would it be so difficult to show what you've tried, and state your problem in a way that expresses that you've encountered a problem, not plainly asking for code. You've had downvotes because you've put so little effort into this question.

Comment: I didn't think it would help people answering the question nor future people reading it for reference, who wouldn't be interested in my life story. I've asked other questions which I give lots of background when I think it helps people answer the question I have.

Comment: @Clinton You could have at least opened your question with "*I'm trying to make a newtype wrapped applicative function a member of Control.Category*, but [...]". That would have given visitors some context.

Comment: @Clinton You may say that, but the fact that you've been downvoted indicates that *it's a bad idea*. Please put effort into a question.

Comment: I am quite fond of this function. I even [wrote a little about it](https://duplode.github.io/posts/applicative-archery.html) a while ago, though you probably won't find it very interesting, as by now you likely have figured it all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be done:

```
composeApplicative p q = (.) <$> p <*> q
```

For more information, [read the documentation for Applicative functors](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Applicative.html), more specifically, the composition law. It is effectively a statement that any `Applicative` instance, `composeApplicative f g <*> x` must always be equal to `f <*> (g <*> x)`.

As a minor technical note, when doing equational reasoning, the left- and right-hand sides of equations must be separated with a single equals sign (`=`). The double-equals sign (`==`) is reserved for [decidable runtime equality checks](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Data-Eq.html).

Comment: "As a minor technical note, when doing equational reasoning, the left- and right-hand sides of equations must be separated with a single equals sign (=). The double-equals sign (==) is reserved for decidable runtime equality checks." This is not a consensus rule; plenty of high-profile Haskellers use `==` for equational reasoning. Not even the GHC documentation follows it consistently; see e.g. [the docs for `Functor` and `Monad`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#t:Functor).

Comment: @LuisCasillas: Point taken. But I think it's useful to distinguish between equality as a *proposition* (which may or may not be decidable), and *decision procedure* for equality (which in general doesn't exist for arbitrary types).